# Как получить значение размера элемента при инспектировании?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как получить значение размера элемента при инспектировании ? Я про `426x360`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раньше можно было так:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//someXpath").size  # {'width':426, 'height': 360}`

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё использовать `getAttribute(аргумент)` метод:

```
width = driver.findElement(image locator).getAttribute("width")
height = driver.findElement(image locator).getAttribute("height")
print(width) # показать ширину
print(height) # показать высоту
```